# how to replace the last matched character in string with last matched character and constant

Tags: c++, regex, c++17

I have a string like,

```
string basestring= "A\B+C+E\FG+\K987+54h\";
```

I have to replace all the occurrence of special character with the same special character and .

Output should be :

```
"A\\B\+C\+E\\FG\+\\K987\+54h\\"
```

Currently I am using the following code to get the result.

```
regex Reg("[^A-Z0-9]", regex_constants::icase);
string help = regex_replace("A\B+C+E\FG+\K987+54h\", Reg, "\\");
```

This will replace all the special characters with \, How to get the last occurred special character ?

Comment: so basically you need escape regular expressions special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
std::regex Reg("[^A-Z0-9]", std::regex_constants::icase);
std::string help = std::regex_replace(R"(A\B+C+E\FG+\K987+54h\)", Reg, R"(\$&)");
```

The replacement is a backslash followed with the match value (the backreference to the whole match is `$&`).

Answer (score 0):

When you do this replacement:

```
regex_replace("A\B+C+E\FG+\K987+54h\", Reg, "\\");
```

you are substituting `\\` exactly for every pattern you match.

To get the desired output, you need to substitute in the matched pattern along with the escape characters, like this:

```
std::regex_replace(R"(A\B+C+E\FG+\K987+54h\)", Reg, "\\$0");
                       // insert \\ before the match ^^^^
```

Also note that the input string needs to escape the special characters, or be written as a raw-string literal.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xG9o8T).

Comment: output is : A\$0B\$0C\$0E\$0FG\$0\$0K987\$054h\$0

Comment: Looks like your replacement string is `\$0`. It needs to be `\\$0`. Click on the demo link, you can play with the code there.

Comment: I am getting the same answer however. I am using visual studio 2017, seems visual studio compiler is not treating $0 as last occurred  match,

Comment: `$0` is the entire matched regex, not the last occurred match. Maybe it's a VS bug, the code should work fine.